# Detecting if iframe src is displayable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'd like to load external websites within an iframe, and if any of those sites employ the use of a frame blocker then I'd like to redirect the user to an error page. There have been a few proposed methods of doing this:

- wait for an onload timeout
- see if iframe src html contents are 'empty' after it loads
- Try to catch an error
- Maintain a database of 'blacklisted' urls

So far, depressingly, I've had the most luck with the last item. The other methods aren't working for the following reasons:

- *waiting for an onload timeout:*

  - onload events fire even with websites that employ frame killers. For example, if I try to access www.google.com, it'll just load empty html structure.
- *seeing if iframe src html contents are 'empty' after it loads*

  - You're unable to access external src contents of an iframe due to the same origin policy.
- *Trying to catch an error:*

  - To my understanding I can only find error handling functions that pertain to errors stemming from your local JS code, and nothing related to errors like `"Refused to display <URL> in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'`/`'DENY'"`.
- *Maintaining a database of 'blacklisted' urls:*

  - This is obviously a bad solution, it's incomprehensive and a big list haha.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding one of these methods. Is there a solution here I'm missing? For context I am doing this mainly in JS + jQuery.

Comment: Spent many hours on this same issue myself one time, and never found a solution. Be curious if one turns up

Comment: Although one thing I never did try was using a server side script to make a head request .. which might be something worth trying.

Comment: Hmm that's worth a shot actually

Comment: One thing that won't catch though is any script that forces the frame page to `top` but might help you narrow down headers that certainly won't work in iframe

Answer (score 0):

I have a temporary fix that uses header information as @charlietfl suggested, though it's not perfect, as you can see under the tests section, not all sites list x-frame options in their headers.

```
<?php 

// checkXFO
// checks x-frame options
// $headers: an array of headers
// returns: nothing
function checkXFO($headers){
    if($headers['X-Frame-Options']==""){
        echo "good to embed! <p>";
    }
    else{
        echo "Denied! <p>";
    }
}

//-----------------------
// tests
//-----------------------

// x-frame option: SAMEORIGIN
// should deny
// > passes
$headerArray = get_headers('http://www.google.com',1); 
checkXFO($headerArray);

// x-frame option: DENY
// should deny
// > passes
$headerArray = get_headers('http://www.facebook.com',1); 
checkXFO($headerArray);

//x-frame option: none
// should accept
// > passes
$headerArray = get_headers('http://wikipedia.org',1); 
checkXFO($headerArray);

//x-frame option: none
// should accept
// > passes
$headerArray = get_headers('http://neopets.com',1); 
checkXFO($headerArray);

//x-frame options: DENY
// should deny
// > fails
$headerArray = get_headers('http://www.yahoo.com',1); 
checkXFO($headerArray);

//x-frame option:none. Redirected x-frame options: DENY
// should deny
// > fails
$headerArray = get_headers('http://www.yahoo.ca',1); 
checkXFO($headerArray);
?>
```